# Google analytics update version to 64bytes

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, google-analytics

I want to move an application in 64 bytes .
But I have a problem with Google Analytics.
In the new version , there is no file " GANTracker.h " .

My methods are in a class I call where I need it.
My existing classes so no longer works , I have to redo everything .

*My initial classes:*

**AnalyticsService.h**

```
#import "GANTracker.h"

@interface AnalyticsService : NSObject

- (id)init;

- (void)startTracker;

- (void)stopTracker;

- (void)restartTracker;

- (BOOL)trackPageview:(NSString *)pageURL;

- (BOOL)trackEvent:(NSString *)category
            action:(NSString *)action
             label:(NSString *)label
             value:(NSInteger)value;

@end
```

**AnalyticsService.m**

```
#import "AnalyticsService.h"
#import "Util.h"
#import "ServicesProxy.h"

@implementation AnalyticsService

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self != nil)
    {}
    return self;
}

- (void)startTracker
{
    [[GANTracker sharedTracker] startTrackerWithAccountID:kAnalyticsAccountId dispatchPeriod:kGANDispatchPeriodSec delegate:nil];

    NSString* appVersion = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(NSString*)kCFBundleVersionKey];
    NSString* numPdvInDb = [[[ServicesProxy defaultServicesProxy]pdvService]getSelectedPdv];
    if([numPdvInDb length] == 0) numPdvInDb = @"null";

    [[GANTracker sharedTracker] setCustomVariableAtIndex:1 name:@"VERSION" value:appVersion scope:kGANSessionScope withError:nil];
    [[GANTracker sharedTracker] setCustomVariableAtIndex:2 name:@"PDV" value:appVersion scope:kGANSessionScope withError:nil];
}

- (BOOL)trackPageview:(NSString *)pageURL
{
    return [[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackPageview:pageURL withError:nil];
}

- (BOOL)trackEvent:(NSString *)category action:(NSString *)action label:(NSString *)label value:(NSInteger)value
{
    return [[GANTracker sharedTracker]trackEvent:category action:action label:label value:value withError:nil];
}

- (void)stopTracker
{
    [[GANTracker sharedTracker] stopTracker];
}

- (void)restartTracker
{
    [[GANTracker sharedTracker] stopTracker];
    [self startTracker];
}

@end
```

**What I tried to redo :**

```
@implementation AnalyticsService

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self != nil)
    {}
    return self;
}

- (void)startTracker
{
    id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:kAnalyticsAccountId];

    NSString* appVersion = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(NSString*)kCFBundleVersionKey];
    NSString* numPdvInDb = [[[ServicesProxy defaultServicesProxy]pdvService]getSelectedPdv];
    if([numPdvInDb length] == 0) numPdvInDb = @"null";

    [tracker set:@"VERSION" value:appVersion];
    [tracker set:@"PDV" value:numPdvInDb];
}


- (BOOL)trackPageview:(NSString *)pageURL
{
    id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

    [tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:pageURL];
    [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView] build]];

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)trackEvent:(NSString *)category action:(NSString *)action label:(NSString *)label value:(NSInteger)value
{
    id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

    [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:category
                                                          action:action
                                                           label:label
                                                           value:nil] build]];

    return YES;
}

- (void)stopTracker
{
    id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

    [tracker ????? ];

}

- (void)restartTracker
{
    [self stopTracker];
    [self startTracker];
}

@end
```

Well, I hope that I have explained well . Sorry for my english (I'm french )

If you have ways to help ...

Thank you in advance for your answers! :)

Comment: what the problem u faced

Comment: The problem is that the methods used do not exist in the new version of GA

Comment: r u using analytics only for screen tracking and event only ,..? or else use

Comment: yes and also to know which version is used , what actions have been taken , how long ...

Comment: simple bro it taken only 15 min to implement r u used pods in your project

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "`GANTracker.h`", try importing "`GAITracker.h`"

Comment: Methods " GANTracker " does not exist in " GAITracker "

Comment: GANTracker existed in older versions of Google Analytics [(here's the documentation for version 1,](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v1/devguide) which talks about GANTracker).  If you want to use the latest Google Analytics, you're going to have to migrate from the older API's.

Comment: Yes , the application used GA v1, but if I want to keep GANTracker I have an error: "ld symbol (s) not found for i386 "

That's why I wanted to use the new version  but I do not know how I tried to migrate by following the documentation ( the code is above) .
Sorry if my questions seem silly , I started in this language